# How can I create a multiple line text so that each line (row) is centered?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 35, 35),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Column(children: const [
                    Text(
                      'Student Space',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text('This is a very very very long text that should be centered just like the first text in this column. I don't want to cut it for each row.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I am expecting the text to look just like when you center a text in Word. I cannot figure out how to do this without splitting the text into seperate ones for each row.

Answer (score 0):

use `"\n"` to change to next line and use `textAlign` as `TextAlign.center` to centre the text

```
Text('Something went wrong \nPlease try again',textAlign: TextAlign.center,);
```